# FileNotFoundException on .dat file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

Propably it's simple error but I'm stuck. I keep a .dat file with a text I want to read in the program in the same package as main and base class, and I've got a FileNotFoundException. I tried to change the file on .txt, getting the URI syntax, but that didn't help. Where's the point?

The main class:

```
package syseks;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class main {

public static syseks.base ba;
public main(syseks.base ba){
    ba = this.ba;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    ba = new base();
    String[] py = ba.loadData('p');
    System.out.print(py);
}

}
```

And the loadData method from base class:

```
public String[] loadData(char param) throws FileNotFoundException{

    List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(param == 'p'){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("py.dat"));   //HERE'S THE CRASH
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            strlist.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
    else{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("wy.dat"));
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            strlist.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }

    String[] da = strlist.toArray(new String[0]);

    return da;
}
```

Comment: "FileNotFoundException" <-- Which, unfortunately, is meaningless. You get `FileNotFoundException` also if you can't access the file because of a permission problem. Paste the full message, or take a plunge into modern Java and use `java.nio.file`.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: py.dat (Can't find the file)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
 at syseks.base.loadData(base.java:28)
 at syseks.main.main(main.java:30)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: and how are you running the program..If running from console,you need to move into root directory first

Comment: Do you know the difference between "current working directory" and "directory where the classes are"?

Comment: @Anirudha That was the point! It works with direct build path! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply an *absolute path* to the `File` constructor argument.  Something like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/foo/proj/myapp/src/syseks/py.dat"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Display the current directory using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. Make sure it's the directory in which you've saved the .dat file.